# Lotus Notes - access everybodies calendar entries .Net

Tags: .net, calendar, interop, lotus-domino, lotus

I am basically trying to get out of our Domino Server a list of all calendar entries for all employees.

This information would then be collated and displayed in a 'Whereabouts' screen within Silverlight within our Intranet system

I can using Interop.Domino access my own mailbox/calendar entries, but I want to itterate through all the mailboxes on the server

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with *Interop.Domino* but you could open the server Domino Directory (usually *names.nsf*) and loop all person documents for example in "People" view. The mail database path and name can be found in *MailFile* item in each person document.

Comment: Not sure I understand, why would I want to access the address book - that surely wouldn't contain users meeting appointments

Comment: It contains a Notes document for each user. Those documents have the information what is the mail/calendar file for that user. You need to open the mail/calendar file/db and get the information from there. If you can get the info from your own mail file you should be able to get it the same way from other mail files. Of course you need to have access to those databases. If it's still unclear, add your current code to your question.

Answer (score 1):

A little more detail to expand on Panu's answer...

The first thing you have to do is establish your access to every mail file.  Without that, you're not going to get anywhere with this project.  If your code is running under your own identity, you probably don't have access to any of the other users mail files.  You may need to have your sysadmins create an ID for your code, add that ID to a Group, and give that Group 'No Access with Read Public Documents' access to all users' mail files.  Note: I am suggesting this level instead of 'Reader' because this will limit your code to only seeing public calendar entries.  Your code will not see any entries that the user has marked 'Private', and your code will not be able to read the users' email messages.  This is consistent with standard Notes/Domino security practices.  'No Access with Read Public Documents' is the same access level that Notes gives to users when you use the built-in delegation feature.

Once your access is established, take the code that you say is successfully opening your own mail database and reading your calendar, take it and make it into a function that is called with parameters for the serverName and and mailFile, using those parameters to replace the strings that you hard-coded in your current code.

Now, write a new main loop that opens the Domino Directory (names.nsf) on a server, opens the "People" view, and loops through all the Person documents.  Read the following two NotesItems: from each document: "MailServer" and "MailFile".  If they are non-blank, call your function with these as parameters.